# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'MyServices' is not a subtype of type 'MyServices' in type cast where

Tags: flutter-getx

I am using getx to configure services in the flutter application and the following error occurred to me and I tried many times but to no avail, the error continues to appear!!

[How can I handle this error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRvzx.png)

The error occurs when trying to initialize the controller for the login class

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnZaH.png)

[myservices class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47rej.png)

[void main()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HDNI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you are using same name for 2 classes. Two different classes with the same name will be considered as 2 different classes.